# What devices does Apple test your app on during app review?

Tags: iphone

We have an app ready for submission to app store. The app is built with 4.0 and is targeted to run on 3.1 and above. We have tested it on iPhone 3gs with 3.x and 4.0, on iPod Touch with 3.1.3 and iphone 3G with 3.x and it works fine.
But on iPhone 3G with 4.0, the app becomes very slow after just half an hour and starts giving low memory warning. Then it crashes. This is not observed on any other device or 3G with 3.x OS. The OS update has made the 3G device terribly slow and even inbuilt apps like Settings are very slow now.

I wanted to know if anyone has any idea what devices and OS apple tests the app with. 3G is no longer on sale. But there has got to be lots of users who still have it. So would Apple reject the app if 3G with ios4 combination kills my app?

Comment: If your app doesn't run acceptably well on it, why would you want to list it as supported? Can't you exclude that as not supported?

Comment: If I exclude iphone 3G with iOS4 testing when submitting the app, I wanted to know whether apple still would test on it. Where exactly can I specify that we do not support that combination?

Comment: I closed this as too localised because in a year we'll have new iPhones or iPods, what then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple typically tests with a iPhone 3GS and an iPhone 4, at least those are the only two that they've ever listed in rejection notices that I've run across.

Either way, I'm whole-heartedly **against** releasing an app that doesn't run well on a device that you are stating you support.  You shouldn't sell/give away something that doesn't work, not even for 99 cents, not for free, not at all.

Take the time to make quality apps, not crApps.  That's what customer service, and more notably personal pride in your product, is all about.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be worried about Apple's tests. If you deliver your software as it is, you will get some angry users on your toes, and that's a big problem.

That way, you should be trying to solve the problem, or excluding the device/OS combination where your app doesn't run well. This way, you will not dissappoint your potential users...

Comment: Where exactly can I specify that we do not support iphone 3G with iOS 4 combination?